# how to prevent user to chose holiday in TableCalendar with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, select, events, calendar

how to prevent user to chose holiday in TableCalendar with flutter?
I have TableCalendar in flutter and holidays, I want to prevet user to select holidays
what should I do?
and here is my code
please note that I reduce the code by deleting colors code from the styling, because stack over flow note, but it should work

```
TableCalendar(
        calendarController: _calendarController,
         holidays: _holidays,
        startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
        calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
          outsideDaysVisible: false,
        ),
        weekendDays: const [DateTime.friday,DateTime.saturday],
        headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
          formatButtonShowsNext: true,
          centerHeaderTitle: true,
          formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
          formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
          ),
          formatButtonVisible: false,
        ),
        onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
        onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
        onCalendarCreated: _onCalendarCreated,
        builders: CalendarBuilders(
          markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
            final children = <Widget>[];
            if (events.isNotEmpty) {
              children.add(
                Positioned(
                  right: 1,
                  bottom: 1,
                  child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
                ),
              );
            }

            return children;
          },
          holidayDayBuilder: (context,date,events) {return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(date.day.toString(),style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),),
            ),
          );
          },
          selectedDayBuilder: (context,date,events) {
            return Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(date.day.toString(),
             style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: font,),
              ),
            ),
          );
          },
          todayDayBuilder: (context,date,events) => Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
            child: Text(date.day.toString(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

the methode that should change

```
 void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    print('day: ${day}');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You assign a function to the constructor property selectedDayPredicate that tells the system whether each of the dates drawn is selected.  Have this function check a list of selected dates to determine this.  The way it works is that as each date is drawn the system provides the assigned function with the date of the day being drawn and if it receives true it draws it as a selected day.

You populate the list of selected dates using the _onDaySelected function you have highlighted, assigning that function to the onDaySelected function you haver highlighted.

When that function is called, store the selected days in a List.  To stop holidays being selected you would add a line to the _onDaySelected function that first checked if the day was a holiday (it appears there is a _holidays function to do just that) and if it is, then just return without adding the date to the list of selected days.